# Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_01 [Map 1]

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

````
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000_0:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 6217 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):4096
        at org.apache.tez.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:334)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:557)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:525)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000_1:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 6217 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):4096
        at org.apache.tez.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:334)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:557)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:525)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000_2:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 6217 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):4096
        at org.apache.tez.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:334)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:557)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:525)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000_3:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 6217 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):4096
        at org.apache.tez.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:334)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:557)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:525)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_01 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_02, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:194, Vertex vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_02 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20220515090633_00caf994-7d63-4dc8-b42d-9e019af7d669); Time taken: 11.497 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000_0:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 6217 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):4096
        at org.apache.tez.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:334)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:557)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:525)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000_1:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 6217 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):4096
        at org.apache.tez.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:334)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:557)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:525)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000_2:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 6217 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):4096
        at org.apache.tez.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:334)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:557)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:525)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1652074645349_0075_3_01_000000_3:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 6217 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):4096
        at org.apache.tez.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:334)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:557)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:525)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_01 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_02, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:194, Vertex vertex_1652074645349_0075_3_02 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1 (state=08S01,code=2```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please set tez.runtime.io.sort.mb to less than the available task memory (MB):4096

It seems you have it set to 6217 and that's an invalid configuration given the task memory is set to 4096.